# Facebook Account Kit Setup

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-account-kit

In the guides, Facebook says

> Add both your Facebook App ID and Account Kit Client Token to your
>   Info.plist file as strings. Make sure you have enabled Account Kit in
>   the App Dashboard. You'll find the Account Kit client token in the
>   Account Kit section of the App Dashboard

However I really have no idea where to enable it. Could anyone please help with a visual guide? I have been trying to find it for 2 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find your Facebook App ID and Account Kit access token if you go to your app in the App Dashboard.

The app dashboard is located at:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/INSERT_YOUR_APP_ID/dashboard/

To add Account Kit click "+Add Product" on the left. The Account Kit page in settings will display your client token, and the main dashboard page will display the Facebook App Id.

Comment: this was what I needed _To add Account Kit click "+Add Product" on the left._